# При запуске Jar файла не работает считывание txt с файла, файла там в принципе нет

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

работаю в программе Eclipse.
Экспортировал Runnable JAR File, но при открытии его на рабочем столе что-то грузиться пол секунды (около мышки колёсико крутиться) и ничего не происходит. Открыл jar файл с помощью WinRAR, там папки data не нашёл, пробовал экспортировать JAR файл, не помогло.
В Jar файле, в папке META-INF изменил содержимое MANIFEST.MF добавив **Main-Class: Main** но ничего не изменилось, подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему.
Ссылка на файлы: `"./RAMdata/RAM_2_1.txt"`

[image: сам файл]

Comment: Очень интересно, но ничего не понятно.  Какой файл вы хотите прочитать (ресурс внутри jar-файла? обычный файл?), и как именно вы пытаетесь это сделать?  Покажите Java-код, в котором вы читаете файл.

Comment: я уже решил проблему, оказывается нужно было хранить дата файл не в jar, а в той же папке, рядом. + ошибка была с версией Java

Comment: Файлы можно хранить и читать и в jar, и на файловой системе, но это делается по-разному.  В целом ни вопрос, ни его решение не стали более понятными.

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы является хранение дата файла рядом c jar файлом, в той же папке\директории. у кого такая же проблема, запускайте через консоль, там выводит ошибки. Если вам ничего не отвечает, то проверьте наличие дата файла около jar